# php redirect not working with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Simple problem:

I have conditions in php like so:

```
if (!$authorized)
   show_site_404();
```

or like so for that matter

```
if (!$logged_on)
    show_login_page();
```

These are obviously toll gates so that we don't have trespassers into parts of the system where only a specific user or only those that are logged on should be able to go.

The code in both these cases simply loads another page than that which was intended by

```
require( MAINPATH . 'site-404.php' );
exit();
```

With Apache, this was never a problem. No settings needed.

With Nginx, it sends all such calls to the frontpage. It's like it doesn't accept an internal "re-direct" if you see what I mean.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually trying to 'redirect' the user or output different html on the current page

Comment: You need to paste your nginx vhost too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with require as this would stop your script with an error message although with errors turned off you probably wouldn't notice this as you run an exit(); to stop execution anyway.

Check the constant variable is including the files, try them in the same directory without mainpath constant.